# PayPal Logo not showing up on checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

We have this issue with a few M1 sites.
The PayPal logo is not showing up on checkout.

The requested URL is

```
https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&buttontype=ecshortcut&locale=en_US` and it just returns an `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

This happened a few times and tends to resolve itself on it's own.
The first time this happened we figured something was up with PayPal's servers but now it's happening very frequently.

We can switch out the image and just call a local image but we'd rather not - love the problem not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same error (connection reset) trying to directly access the URL from the PayPal docs at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECButtonIntegration/

The guide does say this method is Deprecated, though. Probably best to contact PayPal support directly?

Personally, I've just over-ridden the .phtml with a static image of the PayPal button.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Ricky for pointing out that the method is deprecated.

I created a quick module to overwrite the function from get dynamic to get static
https://github.com/treestonemedia/Magento-Paypal-Dynamic-Images